# Printing to a file in C

Tags: c, text-files, output, binary-search-tree

How do I print to an empty `.txt file` I already have created?

I already print the results to the console, and now I want to print to a file named `"Output.txt"`. I've tried a couple of things that haven't worked, but I think it was easier to create a duplicate `printDictionary()` specifically for printing to a file called `printDictionaryToFile()`. I'm a little lost on how to do it though. Can anyone correct me on where I went wrong? I already added an extra `FILE` type called `*out` for my output to a file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define PUNC    " \t\n\r,;.:!()[]{}?'\""
typedef struct node node;

typedef struct node {
    char *word;
    int count;
    node *left;
    node *right;
} node;


void insert(node ** dictionary, char * word) {
    int result;
    node * entry;

    if (word == NULL || dictionary == NULL)
        return;
    if (*dictionary == NULL) {
        entry= (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
        strcpy( entry->word= (char *) malloc(strlen(word) + 1), word);
        entry->left= entry->right= NULL;
        entry->count= 1;
        *dictionary= entry;
        return;
    }
    result = strcmp(word, (*dictionary)->word);
    if ( result < 0 )
        insert(&(*dictionary)->left, word);
    else if (result > 0)
        insert(&(*dictionary)->right, word);
    else
        ++(*dictionary)->count;

    return;
}


void printDictionary(node * dictionary) {
    if (dictionary == NULL)
        return;
    printDictionary(dictionary->left);
    printf( "%s = %d\n", dictionary->word, dictionary->count);
    printDictionary(dictionary->right);

    return;
}


void printDictionaryToFile( node * dictionary ) {
    if (dictionary == NULL)
        return;
    printDictionaryToFile(dictionary->left);
    fprintf(out, "%s = %d\n", dictionary->word, dictionary->count);
    printDictionaryToFile(dictionary->right);
    return;
}


void freeDictionary( node ** dictionary ) {
    if (dictionary == NULL || *dictionary == NULL)
        return;
    freeDictionary(&(*dictionary)->left);
    freeDictionary(&(*dictionary)->right);
    free((*dictionary)->word);
    free(*dictionary);
    *dictionary= NULL;
    return;
}


int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    FILE *fp, *out;
    out = fopen("Output.txt", "w");
    char b[1000], *s;
    node *dictionary= NULL;
    int i;

    for (i= 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        if ((fp = fopen(argv[i], "r")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "File %s can not be opened.\n", argv[i]);
            continue;
        }
        for (s = fgets(b, sizeof(b), fp); s != NULL; s = fgets(b, sizeof(b), fp)) {
            char *word;
            for (word= strtok(b, PUNC); word != NULL; word = strtok(NULL, PUNC))
                insert(&dictionary, strlwr(word));
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    printDictionaryToFile(dictionary);
    printDictionary(dictionary);
    freeDictionary(&dictionary);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use fopen("filename.txt", "w") and fprintf().

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`fprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) function, which is quite similar to [`printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) in the way it works.

Here is an example:

```
FILE *fp;
int myInt = 5;
fp = fopen("Output.txt", "w");// "w" means that we are going to write on this file
fprintf(fp, "This is being written in the file. This is an int variable: %d", myInt);
fclose(fp); //Don't forget to close the file when finished
```

The output on your file would be this:

> This is being written in the file. This is an int variable: 5

Worth to mention that opening the file using `w` as parameter will destroy the file's content every time you open it.

Comment: Ok so does this work for BST's because I see you have the `%d` to print a num. Also does that mean I dont have to alter any of the `printDictionaryToFile()` code everything I need to do is in the `main()`

Comment: using `%d` to print an integer was just a way of demonstrating the similarity of `fprintf` and `printf`. You can use `%s` for strings and so on. In your case, you could use, instead of your printf function, `fprintf(pointerToFile, "%s = %d\n", dictionary->word, dictionary->count );`

Comment: Ok I now it only prints one word I want it to print each like it does in my console what should I do now?

Comment: Actually, if you are using it as said here, `fprintf` would have to write in your file exactly what your `printf` function was writing in your console. What is the output that you are getting?

Comment: well in my console I get this huge list of words with how many times each appears in the text. While in the file I get the same thing except its just one word instead of the entire list. Also I using a function to print the words in the console thats why I thought I should have an identical method to that one.

Comment: Are you opening the file every time you write into it? Remember that, about fopen, "`using w as parameter will destroy the file's content every time you open it.`". You only need to open the file once

Comment: I think imm doing it right ill up date the code on here for you to see.

Comment: you are not passing your `out` pointer to the function, so the function has no `out` variable within it's scope. This won't even compile. Try to make this: `void printDictionaryToFile( node * dictionary, FILE *out )` getting your `out` variable and let me know how did it go

Comment: Just one error in the printTofile where i say `printToFile(dictionary->left)` I need to put something else inside that and putting output doesnt work.

Comment: Pass the variable that you got as a parameter, which would be, following my example, `out`. If it doesn't work I'll update my answer, since this discussion is getting too long for the comments area.

Comment: Thank you I got it running perfectly.